# In Jenkins pipeline sh script, change one command to instead tee output to file, and deal with all the other issues

Tags: bash, jenkins

I have a Jenkins shared library with a bunch of "sh" pipeline steps that execute "mvn" with various goals and parameters.

I started out with a simple requirement: Change all of them so that all the output is "teed" to a file, along with stdout (including stderr).  This by itself is simple to do, but the consequences lead to a chain of issues.

So, first if we start with this:

```
sh('mvn compile')
```

We go to this:

```
sh('mvn compile 2>&1 | tee mvn.out')
```

Done, right?  No.  The problem with this is with the unstated requirement that everything else still works as it did before, like if the mvn command fails with a compile error, that that fails the pipeline step and fails the build.

So, I next try something like this:

```
sh('set -o pipefail; mvn compile 2>&1 | tee mvn.out')
```

This fails with:

```
set: Illegal option -o pipefail
```

That reminds me that the "sh" pipeline step runs Bourne shell, not Bash.

I'm now trying something like this:

```
sh '''
    bash -c set -o pipefail && \
    mvn ... 2>&1 | tee mvn.out
'''
```

This managed to run without any syntax errors.  However, the "pipefail" option didn't work.  It did run the mvn command and tee the output to the file and stdout, but when I forced a character into one of the source files, to force a compile error, this went right on after this command without failing the build, which means the "pipefail" option didn't work.

**Update:**

So, I have a configuration that works.  The line that works is basically this:

```
bash -o pipefail -c "mvn -U <goals> 2>&1 | tee mvn.out"
```

This simplifies the setting of pipefail, and ensures that the proper command line is run.

Comment: `bash -c set -o pipefail` runs command `set` with _no arguments_.

Comment: `-c` takes the command from the first parameter following it. Hence bash sees only the word _set_. This is similar to doing on the command line a `bash -c echo abc`, which also does not print anything.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
sh '''#!/bin/bash
exec > >(tee mvn.out) 2>&1 
mvn ...
'''
```

or:

```
sh '''#!/bin/bash
set -o pipefail && mvn ... 2>&1 | tee mvn.out
'''
```

or:

```
sh '''#!/bin/bash
mvn ... > >(tee mvn.out) 2>&1
'''
```

or if you want to call bash explicitly, you could do a nice prefix:

```
sh '''
bash -o pipefail -c '"$@" 2>&1 | tee mvn.out' -- mvn ...
'''
```

I like the last one, could be stored in a variable:

```
redir = "bash -o pipefail -c '\"\$@\" 2>&1 | tee mvn.out' --"
sh "${redir} mvn ..."
```

Comment: Ok, well, the second one can't work, as Jenkins pipeline "sh" runs Bourne, not Bash. I don't understand what the first one is doing.  Do you believe that the first and third avoids the need for the "pipefail" option?

Comment: Och right, the `#!/bin/bash on the start. Stupid jenkins.